# Want to know how lamda function work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to understand the lambda function in python and got this.

When I store the instance of lambda function in a Dict. It gives the expected result inside of the loop. But outside of the loop, it always stored the last instance, I think.

Can someone explain why this happening? and how the lambda function actually works when we store their instance.

Code:

```py
d = {}

for x in range(4):
    d[x] = lambda n: str(n*x)
    print(d[x](1))

print(d[1](2))
print(d[2](2))
print(d[3](2))
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
6
6
6
```

Comment: `str(n*x)` multiplies `n` by `x` with _whatever the value of `x` is at the time you execute this code._

Comment: You meant to write: `d[x] = lambda n, x=x: str(n*x)`. This captures `x` each time round the loop instead of the last value that `x` has after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given some `x` these 2 functions are equivalent:

```
f1 = lambda n: str(n * x)

def f2(n):
    return str(n * x)
```

all you are doing in addition to that is to put several functions (for several values of `x`) in a dictionary.